# Ways of proving that $A=0$

Tags: reference-request

I was solving a problem where you had to prove that some number $=0$. My strategy was to show that $Ak=A$ for some $k$ not equal to 1, hence $A(k-1)=0$ from which it follows that $A=0$.

Abstracting away from that particular problem I was solving (which I conveniently didn't tell you about), what other ways are there of proving that something $=0$?

Note: Other topics of this sort should be made, e.g. 'Ways of proving that $a\mid b$', etc.

Comment: Good idea. I was thinking about the same thing.

Comment: Every equation can be written is the form something=0. This is too broad for a question.

Comment: You should be careful to specify in which structure you are working. For example $2 \times 4 = 2 \pmod{6}$.

Comment: I do not really know what is part of precalculus algebra; but it seems from a page I just browsed that it contains matrices; see my comment on the answer how this can be relevant. Do you also cover congruences? If yes the comment here is relevant. Generally speaking that $ab=0$ imples that $a=0$ or $b=0$ is not true in all situations. It is true when working with real numbers, but not always.

Comment: Sorry, no, I really don't know this, as high-school curricula vary quite a bit by country. But plenty of others on this site might know, so I will leave this to others.

Answer (score 1):

Here's three possible strategies.

Prove that $A\ge 0$ and $A\le 0$.

Prove that $A^2=0$.

Prove that $-A=A$.

Comment: You should be careful to specify in which structure you claim this to be true; the second is not true for the matrices,  $(0, 1; 0,0)$. The third is not true in characteristic $2$.